# Multiple listView in linear layout Android

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have 4 `listViews` that are being set dynamically. My content exceeds the screen size, so I am unable to show all content.

Here is what it looks like in a `linearLayout` Keep in mind, the "banner"/image will change accordingly to the list. There should be 4. For some reason the bottom list only, as you can see can scroll. (not what I want)

[image: listview1]

**And here is the `xml`**

```
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvSponsors"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>



        <!--Gold-->

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvGold"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>


        <!--Silver-->


            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvSilver"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>


        <!--Bronze-->


            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvBronze"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**And if I set the root view to `scrollView` I get this;**

[image: ListVeiw2]

**And my `xml` for the scroll view**

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/chainlink">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvSponsors"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
        <!--Gold-->

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvGold"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

        <!--Silver-->
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvSilver"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>


        <!--Bronze-->


            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/platinumhead"/>

            <ListView
                    android:layout_margin="8sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/lvBronze"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
 </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

My content is obviously too big for the screen so I will need a `ScrollView` that would scroll the entire page simultaneously. How do I fix my `xml` or `java` to do this?

Comment: 1. Multiple listviews one after another is not a good idea. Find a way to combine them into one listview. If there's no way to do that, then maybe consider having the lists side by side in a ViewPager. 2. Don't put a ListView inside of a ScrollView and vice versa, they will contend with each other for touch events and your UI will have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can never use scrollview + listview together. You can use either scrollview or listview. why you use four listview you can do this easily with section listview.